# A very simple d3 data join adds the new elements in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.4/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-T+1zstV6Llwh/zH+uoc1rJ7Y8tf9N+DiC0T3aL0+0blupn5NkBT52Avsa0l+XBnftn/14EtxpsztAWsmiAaqfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
    var data = {
        "Domains": [ "Domain 1", "Domain 2", "Domain 3" ]
    };
    d3.selectAll('#domains ul li')
        .data(data.Domains)
        .join("li")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Domains</h2>
<div id="domains"><ul></ul></div>
</body>
```

Here is my very simple code. I am expecting it to create `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` element, one for each Domain.
But it creates them between the head and the body!
The resulting html (as gleaned from Chrome inspector) is:

```
<html><head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.4/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-T+1zstV6Llwh/zH+uoc1rJ7Y8tf9N+DiC0T3aL0+0blupn5NkBT52Avsa0l+XBnftn/14EtxpsztAWsmiAaqfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
    var data = {
        "Domains": [ "Domain 1", "Domain 2", "Domain 3" ]
    };
    d3.selectAll('#domains ul li')
        .data(data.Domains)
        .join("li")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });
</script>
</head><li>Domain 1</li><li>Domain 2</li><li>Domain 3</li>
<body>
<h2>Domains</h2>
<div id="domains"><ul></ul></div>

</body></html>
```

Clearly I am doing something stupid - can anyone point out what it is?

I then modified my script as follows:

```
<script>
    var data = {
        "Domains": [ "Domain 1", "Domain 2", "Domain 3" ]
    };
    d3.select('#domains ul')
        .selectAll('li')
        .data(data.Domains)
        .join("li")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });
</script>
```

In this instance, no `<li>` items are added anywhere, and the text function is not even called.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you select with `d3.selectAll` has no bearing on where an element is inserted in the DOM.  What you want to use is `selection.selectAll`

Joins and enters append elements to a parent: you haven't specified a parent, so the elements are just entered into the page as the parent is the document itself by default if using `d3.selectAll`.

Instead select your parent element, the `ul` and then using that selection, do the join: this means any entered elements will be appended to the parent element we selected, the `ul`:

```
d3.select("#domains ul") // return a selection of a parent element
  .selectAll("li")       // select children we have or want to have
  .data(data.Domains)
  .join("li")            // enter/update/exit children li elements
  ...
```

Often you'll see patterns where the selection of the parent is saved with a variable.

*But we have one more problem, your code is in the document head, it runs before the rest of the document loads, so you won't be able to select the `ul`. If you place the script at the end of the body, you'll avoid that, or alternatively you can use the document.ready method. This is also why your `li` elements are added in between the head and the body: append adds things as the last child, but these elements can't be appended after the body as the body hasn't been loaded yet*

Here's a working example:

```js
var data = {
        "Domains": [ "Domain 1", "Domain 2", "Domain 3" ]
    };
    
    let ul = d3.select("#domains ul");
    ul.selectAll("li")
      .data(data.Domains)
      .join("li")
      .text(function(d) {
          return d;
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<h2>Domains</h2>
<div id="domains"><ul></ul></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. In my code before I cut it down to post here, the selects were all run after the window had loaded. But I didn't understand how selectAll/join worked, and I think I do now!